# Как сделать чтобы при клике на таб он стал активным и у него поменялся цвет шрифта?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ребят есть 4 таба. Табы рабочие то есть при клике на них открываются их секции. Проблема в том что при клике на сам таб они не меняют цвет чтобы показать на каком  табе сейчас нахожусь.

```js
var tabsLink = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-tabs a'),
  tabsElement = document.querySelectorAll('.tab-pane'),
  photoElements = document.querySelectorAll('.col-pr'),
  i;

tabsElement[0].classList.add('tab-open');

var showTabs = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var targetElement = document.querySelectorAll(this.getAttribute('href'));
  for (i = 0; i < targetElement.length; i++) {

    if (targetElement[i].classList.contains('tab-open')) {
      return false;
    } else targetElement[i].classList.add('tab-open');
  }

  targetElement = document.querySelectorAll(".tab-pane.tab-open:not(" + this.getAttribute('href') + ")");
  for (i = 0; i < targetElement.length; i++) {
    targetElement[i].classList.remove('tab-open');
  }
};
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('closeButton');

[].forEach.call(buttons, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    el.close('.nameToClose').style.display = 'none';
  });
});

var show_modal = function(event) {
  var photo_elem = event.target.getElementsByClassName('modal-for-photo')[0];
  photo_elem.style.display = 'block';
};

for (i = 0; i < tabsLink.length; i++) {
  tabsLink[i].addEventListener('click', showTabs);
};

for (i = 0; i < photoElements.length; i++) {
  photoElements[i].addEventListener('click', show_modal);
}
```

```css
.tabs-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
}

.tab-holder {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.nav-tabs {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 18px;
  padding: 0;
}
   .tab-pane{
        display: none;
        bottom: 0;
        left:0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top:0;
    }

.nav-tabs ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-tabs li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Frutiger;
  src: url(fonts/TradeGothicLTStd.otf);
}

.nav-tabs a {
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.tab-pane {
  display: none;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 0;
}

.tab-open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs-wrapper">
  <div class="tab_holder">
    <ul class="nav-tabs" id="tabs">
      <li class="current"><a href="#tabs1" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-1">VIDEOS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs2" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-2">COLLECTION</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs3" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-3">LOOKBOOK</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tabs4" data-toggle="tab" id="tab-4">FIND A STORE</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: иными словами у меня сейчас вот так]

Иными словами у меня сейчас как на первой картинке, а хочу чтобы было как на второй

[image: А хочу чтобы было вот так]

Comment: @air вы не знаете как это можно сделать ?

Comment: *Табы рабочие то есть при клике на них открываются их секции*, добавьте код javascript в вопрос, чтобы табы работали.

Comment: @Alex добавил js

Comment: в html нет `tab-pane`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вот зачем вставлять свой джаваскрипт везде где можно и нельзя, когда альтернативные задачи на CSS работают намного быстрее.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
nav{
  width:200px;
  height:250px;
  background:#555;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:20px;
}
li{
  text-align:center;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:bold;
  width:100%;
}
label{
  display: block;
  width:100%;
}
span{
  width:calc(100% - 8px);
  display:block;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}
input[name=select]{
  display:none;
}
input[name=select]:checked + span{
  color:orange;
  border-right: solid  8px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label><input type="radio" name="select"><span>videos</span></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="radio" name="select"><span>collection</span></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="radio" name="select"><span>lookbook</span></label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label><input type="radio" name="select"><span>find a store</span></label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: а функциональность самих табов не изменится ? Попробуйте сделать тут так как у меня теперь переходы не работают  https://jsfiddle.net/h8wojdtq/

Comment: @Anton, нет конечно. С чего вдруг она должна меняться?

Comment: ну вот попробуйте у меня все сломалось что -то @Lestalab

Comment: не знаю вот я сделал как вы но сам функционал сломался

Comment: попробовали ? при клике на любой из табов контент не меняется теперь , а просто все переключается

Comment: не получилось да ?